# adding Searchview to my listview

Tags: android, listview, search

please help me I want to add searchview like this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9yC8XGaSv4)

to my listview in MainActivity , Actually I tired but I get crash when I open the app

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {



public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    // 1. pass context and data to the custom adapter
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, generateData());

    //2. setListAdapter
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

private ArrayList<Item> generateData() {
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    items.add(new Item("item1", "description1"));
    items.add(new Item("item2", "description2"));
    items.add(new Item("item3", "description3"));

    return items;

}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the code where you add the `SearchView` as well as the logcat showing where the exception happens?

Comment: In fast I added it in wrong way because I'm beginner, I posted what I watched in the video

Comment: If you don't post more code, we won't be able to help you...